# c++ virtual function call for object

Tags: c++, object, polymorphism

Learning C++ with help of Bruce Eckel "Thinking in C++". Stuck in exercise 30. Here it is:

> If function calls to an object passed by value weren’t early-bound, a
>   virtual call might access parts that didn’t exist. Is this possible?
>   Write some code to force a virtual call, and see if this causes a
>   crash. To explain the behavior, examine what happens when you pass an
>   object by value.

I can understand result of calling virtual function for object, but I can not understand how to force compiler to do it, without proper constructors called.

Is there a way to treat one object as another without calling proper constructors or operators (for type conversion)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bruce is trying to illustrate *object slicing*, a situation when a polymorphic object is passed by value.

Here is how you can do it:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct hello {
    virtual void say() { cout << "hello" << endl; }
};
struct world : public hello {
    virtual void say() { cout << "world" << endl; }
};
void force(hello h) {
    h.say();
}
int main() {
    world w;
    w.say();
    force(w);
    return 0;
}
```

This code outputs ([link to ideone](http://ideone.com/mD0DT))

```
world
hello
```

even though you'd expect an object of type `world` to "say" `world`, not `hello`. C++ compiler is smart in noticing that `w` is passed to `hello` by value, so it adjusts the vtable to avoid calls of methods in the derived class.

---

Bonus exercise to test if you understand passing by reference: can you modify my code so that it prints `world` `world`? You are allowed to insert a single character.

Comment: True, although I never understood why anyone would expect `world`'s `say()` to get called. `h` is a copied, completely different object with a different type.

Comment: @Alex Programmers previously exposed to other polymorphic languages get surprised when they see `hello` printed, because object slicing does not happen in Java, C#, or Objective-C (and that's a good thing; object slicing behavior is an attempt at fixing something that shouldn't have been allowed in the first place).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: alternatively, object slicing is a valiant attempt to satisfy the Liskov Substitution Principle -- since it is possible to use a `Base` to initialize a `Base`, then it should also be possible to use a `Derived` to initialize a `Base`, since a `Derived` is a `Base`. I'm not necessarily claiming that this is the best conceivable application of LSP to value types, but there it is. The equivalent thing does happen in Java if you choose to write a `Base` constructor that takes a `Base`, but normally you *don't* choose to do that, you `clone()` instead.

Comment: Oh, and in my LSP-induced view, the mistake if any is to call `Base(const Base &)` a *copy constructor* in the first place, since it does not necessarily copy its argument. It copies the base class sub-object of its argument. If we called it "slice construction", "slice assignment" and "pass-by-slice" then we might help clue the Java folks that something funny is going on in C++ before they fall foul of it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

although objects can't be converted from one type to another without proper operators, you can use pointers and cast using either static_cast<> or dynamic_cast<> or reinterpret_cast<>

Comment: The exercise is about calling virtual function for object, not pointer or reference.

Comment: @user1641854: you can use a pointer or reference to the object to make a virtual call on that object, though. In fact that's the *only* way.